# How to compare data in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am using the condition,but it don't go to the if condition, every time goes to the else condition.

```
 if ([[dict2 valueForKey:@"meeting_location"] isEqual:@""])
    {
        lbllocation.text = @"-----";

    }
    else
    {
        lbllocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@",[dict2 valueForKey:@"meeting_location"]];

    }
```

Output came from Webservice:-

```
        "meeting_location" = "";
        "meeting_time" = "";
        "meeting_with" = "";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Below Code** -

```
 if ([[dict2 valueForKey:@"meeting_location"] length] == 0)
{
    lbllocation.text = @"-----";
}
else
{
    lbllocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@",[dict2 valueForKey:@"meeting_location"]];

}
```

Hopefully this will work here.